# Myth over Microservice and Rest API

Tags: microservices

I would like to get some clarity on terminology of microservices.
Reference to the diagram mentioned below.

All Represents the Microservice Architecture

1. Microservice - Does it refer the service which are exposed as API to channel [ Be it browser / Native app / Host ] or even the service which not exposed [ Underlying

- Generic
- Orchestrated
- Atomic

2. As per the diagram, Links from orchestrated to atomic were mentioned.
   Does it have to be always a [REST/ HTTP over call] or is it can be normal Java library method call packaged in the same runnable package.

All tutorials says / goes 1 Microservice = 1 Rest based service or anything exposed as controller to be called from
Can we call library or DAO Generic Service also a microservice?

Microservice Architecture ViewPoint

[image]

Microservice ViewPoint 2

[image]

Comparison

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it refer the service which are exposed as API to channel or even the service which not exposed

A microservice is a service that *serve a business need* - they are "Componentization via Services" - componentes of a bigger system, so they don't necessary need to be exposed to external world, but they can be.

> Does it have to be always a REST/ HTTP over call, or is it can be normal Java library method call packaged in the same runnable package.

Microservices communicate over **network**, but it does not have to be HTTP / REST, it can also be a Kafka topic or gRPC or something else. The important part is that they must be **independently deployable** e.g. you can upgrade a single microservice without needing to change another service at the same time.

See [Martin Fowler - Microservices - 9 characteristics](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) for the most commonly accepted definition.

Comment: As perthe Diagram, above , Do you mean Atomic Core [ Be it Service Implementation wrapper over a DAO] can be invoked via Dependency Injection and still called as Microservice or becomes eligible to call as microservice


Then If it is going to be injected as DI [Depedency Injection], it becomes just a Dependency Library and not as a deployable library

Comment: https://kylegenebrown.medium.com/whats-the-right-size-for-a-microservice-bf1740370d47

Comment: A library is not a Microservice

Comment: Thanks Jonas
Can you give example with real  time Java based microservice
.if a microservice will not be invoked as endpoint call, bit needed as dependency service from other orchestration service

How do you bundle (refer my example those atomic or core) is mentioned as a service
If u put the dependency service as a jar and add in pot of main caller service. As per your defn called service is not a microservice

Comment: As per the example 
 Lets say Orchestrated Service wanted to talk to Atomic Service ,which inturn talks to a database

Comment: PaymentOrchestratedService >  want to use Account ValidationService  [ which is atomic], when you say Accountvalidationservice as microservice,  do we pack this along with bundle of Payment orchestrated ?